Possible relation between causal-net condensation and algebraic K theory
Causal-net condensation is a natural construction which takes a symmetric monoidal category or permutative category $\mathcal{S}$ as input date and produces a functor $\mathcal{L}_\mathcal{S}: \mathbf{Cat}\to \mathbf{Set}$ defined on the category $\mathbf{Cat}$ of small categories and functors. Causal-net condensation is defined in arXiv:2201.08963.
If we consider the path functor $\mathcal{P}:\mathbf{Top}\to \mathbf{Cat}$ which takes topological spaces and continuous mappings to their path categories and corresponding functors, and compose it  with $\mathcal{L}_S$, we get a functor  $\mathbf{H}_\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{L}_S\circ\mathcal{P}:\mathbf{Top}\to\mathbf{Set}$.
There is also a famous Segal K theory functor, which also takes a symmetric monoidal category or permutative category $\mathcal{S}$ as input date and produces a connected spectra (a generalized homology), denoted by $\mathbf{K}_{\mathcal{S}}:\mathbf{Top}\to\mathbf{Set}$.
So a natural question arises: what is the relation between the two functors $\mathbf{H}_\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{L}_S\circ\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathbf{K}_{\mathcal{S}}$.
I guess that in some sense, $\mathbf{H}_\mathcal{S}$ should be a natural extension of $\mathbf{K}_{\mathcal{S}}$, just like homology groups are generalizations of Picard groups.
